# apache-atlas installation on MS Azure HDInsight spark-cluster

Tags: apache-atlas

I have installed Apache-atlas (embedded/non-prod) version on MS Azure HDInsight Spark cluster and it is functional. However, I am not able to start Apache-Atlas on production ready/multinode cluster. Has anybody done that? Is it a good idea to install Apache-Atlas on a Spark cluster after installing all the pre-requisite services(hbase, kafka, solr) manually on the cluster?